# need a neat way to create a dynamic facebook sharing technique with custom parameters

Tags: jquery, facebook

Since Sharer's ability to accept custom parameters is dead which was the easiest way for a noob like me, I am a bit puzzled with all the FB.ui n OGP talk everywhere. I am not sharing via any app. So do not suggest a method that needs any app_id.

I have a bootstrap modal which is dynamically populated from database depending on a url query string. I need a button to share the modal content.

I was thinking of adding og meta tags to the page that contains the modal, depending on the very same query string using " jquery $('head').append() " on load. then the share button will trigger the share dialogue & OGP will pull the data from the metadata & populate the dialogue.

Comment: you can´t add metatags with javascript. the facebook crawler ignores javascript.

Comment: You could use the Feed dialog instead, that still accepts those parameters. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://example.com
```

This still works.

In the past, web developers were able to customize those elements by adding additional query parameters to the share dialog URL:

```
p[title] = Custom Title
p[summary] = Custom Description
p[images][0] = Custom Thumbnail Image
```

For parameters use og meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Something" />
```

For og protocol see: http://ogp.me/

For feed dialog see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2

Comment: I have tried sharer.. it shares the url correctly.. but even adding og meta tags.. all that is getting shared is the page title & domain name. not the meta contents!

Comment: I have tried to use share dialogue.. as feed dialogue will need an app to redirect the url. so an app id is needed.

Comment: App Id is a must in all facebook activity now a days. Even lame iframes.

Comment: does share dialogue need app id too? is it that much necessary?

Comment: if sharer.php picks the wrong tags, refresh them in the debugger

Comment: Ok finally it's working.. though the thumbnail is not getting pulled. wonder why. Thanx man. I added the meta tags & the contents are dynamic which are pulled from database depending on the query parameter!

Comment: Great. Facebook documentation is bizarre though :)